# How to fix error: RenderBox was not laid out: ..... useing flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I need your help! I've created a new empty flutter project, run the main.dart - everything worked. So far so good.

When I change code in the main.dart, just to add another HomePage, it chrashed.

I got the following failure: "**RenderBox was not laid out: RenderPadding#9cccd relayoutBoundary=up12 NEEDS-PAINT 'package:flutter/src/rendering/box.dart': Failed assertion: line 1979 pos 12: 'hasSize'"**
caused by the box.dart file which I thought is generated.

I've found results for the failures in the main.dart, but there are more failures in the MainActivity.kt, GeneratedPluginResistrant.java.

**MainActivity.kt:**

*path: android/app/src/main/kotlin/com/example/via_flutter/MainActivity.kt*

*failure*:

[image]

the red marked words say: "Unresolved reference: embedding", "Unresolved reference: FlutterActivity"

Why can't it import the src?

**GeneratedPluginResistrant.java:**

*path: android\app\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\GeneratedPluginRegistrant.java*

*failure*:
[image]

and again "Cannot resolve symbol 'Keep'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'NonNull'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'Log'", "Cannot resolve symbol 'FlutterEngine'"

I've tried to Migrate it to Androix, but it didn't worked saying this error :
[image]

and changed the Code to *SizedBox including the height*:

```
          Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(30, 0, 20, 0),
                      child: Column(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 200,
                              child: Center(
                                child: ListTile(
                                  title: _buildCupertinoItem(_selectedCupertinoLanguage),
                                  onTap: _openCupertinoLanguagePicker,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ),
```

This is my **Main.dart**:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:language_picker/language_picker.dart';
import 'package:language_picker/languages.dart';
import 'package:easy_debounce/easy_debounce.dart';
import 'package:font_awesome_flutter/font_awesome_flutter.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const HomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  late TextEditingController projectTFController;
  late TextEditingController serverTFController;
  late TextEditingController workstationTFController;

  Language _selectedCupertinoLanguage = Languages.german;

  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  //final animationsMap = {
  //  'containerOnPageLoadAnimation': AnimationInfo(
  //    trigger: AnimationTrigger.onPageLoad,
  //    duration: 800,
  //    delay: 1500,
  //    fadeIn: true,
  //    initialState: AnimationState(
  //      opacity: 0,
  //    ),
  //    finalState: AnimationState(
  //      opacity: 1,
  //    ),
  //  ),
  //};

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //startPageLoadAnimations(
    //  animationsMap.values
    //      .where((anim) => anim.trigger == AnimationTrigger.onPageLoad),
    //  this,
    //);

    projectTFController = TextEditingController();
    serverTFController = TextEditingController();
    workstationTFController = TextEditingController();
  }

  void _openCupertinoLanguagePicker() => showCupertinoModalPopup<void>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return LanguagePickerCupertino(
          pickerSheetHeight: 200.0,
          onValuePicked: (Language language) => setState(() {
            _selectedCupertinoLanguage = language;
            debugPrint(_selectedCupertinoLanguage.name);
            debugPrint(_selectedCupertinoLanguage.isoCode);
          }),
        );
      });

  Widget _buildCupertinoItem(Language language) => Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Text("+${language.name}"),
      const SizedBox(width: 8.0),
      Flexible(child: Text(language.name))
    ],
  );

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFFF6F6F6),
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Container(
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
            constraints: const BoxConstraints(
              maxWidth: 375,
              maxHeight: 812,
            ),
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 20, 20, 20),
              child: Column(
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 20, 0, 140),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        const Text(
                          'Via',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                          style:
                          TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'carlito',
                            color: Color(0xFF00365E),
                            fontSize: 40,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                        const Text(
                          'dat',
                          style:
                          TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: 'carlito',
                            color: Color(0xFF00365E),
                            fontSize: 40,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(30, 0, 20, 0),
                          child: Column(
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                SizedBox(
                                  height: 200,
                                  child: Center(
                                    child: ListTile(
                                      title: _buildCupertinoItem(_selectedCupertinoLanguage),
                                      onTap: _openCupertinoLanguagePicker,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ]),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 20, 10, 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: serverTFController,
                      onChanged: (_) => EasyDebounce.debounce(
                        'serverTFController',
                        const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                            () => setState(() {}),
                      ),
                      autofocus: true,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Server',
                        labelStyle:
                        const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'carlito',
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Enter a Servername',
                        hintStyle:
                        const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'carlito',
                          color: Color(0x8000365E),
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFA7A7A7),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFA7A7A7),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        suffixIcon: const FaIcon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.starOfLife,
                          color: Color(0xFFFF0000),
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'carlito',
                        color: Color(0xFF00365E),
                        fontSize: 22,
                        //lineHeight: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 20, 10, 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: projectTFController,
                      onChanged: (_) => EasyDebounce.debounce(
                        'projectTFController',
                        const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                            () => setState(() {}),
                      ),
                      autofocus: true,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Project',
                        labelStyle:
                        const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'carlito',
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Enter a Projectname',
                        hintStyle:
                        const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'carlito',
                          color: Color(0x8000365E),
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFA7A7A7),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFA7A7A7),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                        suffixIcon: const FaIcon(
                          FontAwesomeIcons.starOfLife,
                          color: Color(0xFFFF0000),
                          size: 22,
                        ),
                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'carlito',
                        color: Color(0xFF00365E),
                        fontSize: 22,
                        //lineHeight: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(10, 20, 10, 10),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: workstationTFController,
                      onChanged: (_) => EasyDebounce.debounce(
                        'workstationTFController',
                        const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                            () => setState(() {}),
                      ),
                      autofocus: true,
                      obscureText: false,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Workstation',
                        labelStyle:
                        const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'carlito',
                          color: Colors.black,
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                        hintText: 'Enter a Workstation',
                        hintStyle:
                        const TextStyle(
                          fontFamily: 'carlito',
                          color: Color(0x8000365E),
                          fontSize: 22,
                        ),
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFA7A7A7),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(
                          borderSide: const BorderSide(
                            color: Color(0xFFA7A7A7),
                            width: 1,
                          ),
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0),
                        ),
                        filled: true,
                        fillColor: Colors.white,
                      ),
                      style: const TextStyle(
                        fontFamily: 'carlito',
                        color: Color(0xFF00365E),
                        fontSize: 22,
                        //lineHeight: 2,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 20, 0, 2800),
                    child: ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () {
                        debugPrint('confirmBtn pressed ...');
                      },
                      child: const Text("Confirm"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          )//.animated([animationsMap['containerOnPageLoadAnimation']]),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Can someone please help me?

Comment: As for the error message, It is showing layout overflow issue, Can you include an image that you are trying to archive?

Comment: someone told me the solution: I forgot to add width, no it is working

Comment: I've tested your snippet on simplified version, It just having unbound height. It is necessary to share [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but you've included full code which will hard for others to test. and desire output image can tell what exactly you are trying to archive.

Answer (score 0):

hmmm the code is a bit crowded but i think if you set mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,

into inner column, your issue must be solved